# Convergence radius of $\sqrt{\cos(z)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

*Compute the first 3 non zero terms of the Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{\cos(z)}$ at $z=0$ and determine its convergence radius, considering only the principal branch of the square root.*

I've computed the first 3 non zero terms which the problem asks for:

$$f(z)=1-\frac{1}{4}z^2-\frac{1}{96}z^4$$

1. But, how do I determine the radius of convergence if I don't have the general expression for the Taylor series?
2. And, what does it mean by the principal branch of the square root? I understand what the principal branch of the logarithm is, but I didn't know it existed for the square root.

Comment: It's the branch with $\sqrt{1} = 1$. That doesn't influence the radius of convergence, a choice of the branch of the square root only determines a sign. You know that the Taylor series converges in the largest disk where the function is analytic? What problems for analyticity occur here?

Comment: Hmm, you mean $\cos(z)>0$, so $|z|<\frac{\pi}{2}$, right?

Comment: $\cos$ has complex values, so $\cos z > 0$ doesn't make much sense. But a zero is a problem for the square root indeed, so $\cos z \neq 0$ is a good guess. One must then see that you can't define $\sqrt{\cos z}$ analytically around a zero of $\cos$.

Answer (score 1):

The answers were obtained in comments, with the help from Daniel Fischer:

- radius of convergence is $\pi/2$, because $\sqrt{\cos z}$ is holomorphic for $|z|<\pi/2$, but is not holomorphic in any neighborhood of $\pi/2$, where cosine is zero. (One way to show this is to notice that the derivative of $\sqrt{\cos z}$ is unbounded there.)
- the principal branch of square root (or of any other fractional power) is defined so that the power of $1$  is equal to $1$. This convention removes the ambiguity present in the choice between two possibilities for the square root.

Comment: How can you see that $\sqrt{\cos z}$ can be defined holomorphic up to radius $\pi /2$? Maybe there is some other problem which causes the convergence radius to be less?